# How to do custom Model Binder in C# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, model-binding

I have a Model:

```
public class MyModel 
{    
    public MyModel (int ID, string Name)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.Name= Name;               
    }    

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

In my Controller, I assign value to this model. It's a list of items that I want to show on the view.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{    
    IEnumerable<MyModel> myModel = from q in tbl1.AsEnumerable()
        select new MyModel (q.ID, q.Name);

    return View(myModel);
}
```

This is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<xxx_website.Models.MyModel >    

@foreach (var item in Model)
{        
    @Html.EditorFor(model => item.Name)
}    

<input type="submit" value="Submit"  />
```

When I click the Submit button, I want to pass the MyModel data to the controller.
But, it's always null.

I think I need to `BindModel` and write some thing in `protected void Application_Start()` function. But, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What you have is not a "custom" model. There's not such thing as custom model. All models are user-defined. And, you don't need a custom model-binder for binding to a list. This question has already been asked too many times on SO. Check this: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Two problems.

`MyModel` does not have a parameterless constructor. The `DefaultModelBinder` will not work without one so add one

```
public class MyModel
{
  public MyModel() {} // add parameterless constructor
  public MyModel (int ID, string Name)
  {
    this.ID = ID;
    this.Name= Name;               
  }  
}
```

In you view your are creating inputs with the same name (and ID which is invalid html). Either create a custom EditorTemplate for `MyModel` and use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m)` (not in a foreach loop) or change the collection to `IList` and use a `for` loop so the inputs are correctly named with indexers

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[0].Name)
}
```

In both cases your html will be

```
<input type="text" name="[0].Name" ...>
<input type="text" name="[1].Name" ...>
...
```

which will correctly bind to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(IEnumerable<MyModel> myCollection)
{
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. The for-loop doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @ataravati, what do you mean it makes no sense - its creating a textbox for each `Name` property of `MyModel` in the collection

Comment: @ataravati, and BTW, I created a project using the code above with OP's model and it does work. Perhaps you should try it.

Comment: @ataravati - The answer is not wrong, and it does make sense.  The reason the OP's code doesn't work is that a foreach loop does not create the necessary indexers in expression of the html helper, but a for loop (that uses an indexer) does.

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to do the way you want before but now I always using Object Modal in View not using Collection
My way is :
I have custom Modal

```
public class MyModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Item> MyItems;
}

public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

And in controller I add collection to MyModel

```
public ActionResult Create()
{    
   MyModel myModel = new MyModel();
   myModel.MyItems = from q in tbl1.AsEnumerable()
    select new MyModel (q.ID, q.Name);

   return View(myModel);
}
```

Note : In view you have to put your modal to form to submit

```
@model xxx_website.Models.MyModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
 }

 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
 {
     for (int i = 0; i< Model.MyItems.Count; i++)
     {
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyItems[i].Name)
     }
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 }
```

And the last is in controller you have post action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(MyModel modal)
    {
        IEnumerable<Item> myItems = modal.MyItems; // your item here
        return View();
    }
```

It's my way. You can try it and comment here

Comment: @user1348351, _"it works"_? This wont work. It renders inputs with the same name (which are not indexed) so the property `myItems` will be null on postback

Comment: @StephenMuecke : You're right. My code doesn't work, all inputs with the same name. I trick its by using "for" not "foreach" with my new code. You can see. And it's work with me. myItems not null when postback and I have new data from I input. Thanks

Comment: @user1348351 : I edited my code. It's new. You can try it, it's work with me

Comment: @VõSơnHà, So having essentially copied my answer, your now pointing out to me that it works!

Comment: @StephenMuecke : Sorry. I often use modal with Enum attribute, so I feel your way is difference. But I see, it's the same. Vote up your post but I don't have enough reputations